# Error loading stopwords: <urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

While downloading NLTK stopwords , I am getting the following error
**[nltk_data] Error loading stopwords: <urlopen error [Errno 110]
[nltk_data]     Connection timed out>**
The code used is

```
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
```

I also tried the following command and got the same error

```
python -m nltk.downloader stopwords
```

Thanks